# In pandas, i have 2 columns(ID and Name). If ID is assigned to more than one name how do i replace duplicates with first occurance

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

[image]

[image]

Image with the csv file with the two columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.drop_duplicates('Salesperson_1')
```

Or maybe need:

```
df.groupby('Salesperson_1')['Salesperson_1_ID'].transform('first')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Salesperson_1':['a','a','b'],
                   'Salesperson_1_ID':[4,5,6]})

print (df)
  Salesperson_1  Salesperson_1_ID
0             a                 4
1             a                 5
2             b                 6

df1 = df.drop_duplicates('Salesperson_1')
print (df1)
  Salesperson_1  Salesperson_1_ID
0             a                 4
2             b                 6

df.Salesperson_1_ID = df.groupby('Salesperson_1')['Salesperson_1_ID'].transform('first')
print (df)
  Salesperson_1  Salesperson_1_ID
0             a                 4
1             a                 4
2             b                 6
```

Comment: But if the id column is null i.e ' ', then it replaces the entire name column with the first one

Comment: I think you can filter first by: `df = df[df['Salesperson_1_ID'].notnull() & (df['Salesperson_1_ID'] != '')]`

Answer (score 0):

## Pandas.groupby.first()

if your DataFrame is called `df`, you could just do this:

```
df.groupby('Salesperson_1_ID').first()
```

Comment: also need to replace other duplicate names with the first matched id's names

Comment: In that case you should `df.drop_duplicates('Salesperson_1')` first, as mentioned by @jezrael